# Need help solving Firebase query in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to see if this "employee" has a service where the serviceComplete field is false (in other words trying to see if this employee has an active service that is not complete) if a Toast message pops up letting the employee know he cannot accept more services has he has an active one. If not the employee should be able to accept the service.

My problem is **no matter what I do this firebase query seems to think there are documents in my DB that do not exist**. Every time I go to accept the service it displays the toast. Meaning there is a collection "services" where a document has the field "serviceCompleted" which is equal to "false" but in my DB there is no collection "services" under employees

[My database showing no collection "services" exist underneath "employees"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEEfm.png)

and here is my Kotlin code

```
fun setButton(serviceID: String, eID: String){

        val btnAcceptService = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnAcceptService)
        btnAcceptService.setOnClickListener {
            val queryEmpServices = database.collection("employees").document(eID).collection("services").whereEqualTo("serviceComplete", false)

            queryEmpServices.get().addOnSuccessListener { documents ->

                if (documents != null){
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"You already have a service active!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                }else {

                    database.collection("services").document(serviceID).update("saccept", true).addOnSuccessListener {

                        database.collection("services").document(serviceID).get().addOnSuccessListener { document ->

                            if (document != null) {

                                val Location = document.get("ulocation").toString()
                                val serviceType = document.get("serviceType").toString()
                                val uComment = document.get("ucomment").toString()
                                val uID = document.get("uid").toString()

                                if (document.getBoolean("saccept") == true) {

                                    database.collection("users").document(document.get("uid").toString()).collection("services").document(serviceID).update("saccept", true).addOnSuccessListener {

                                        database.collection("employees").document(mAuth.currentUser!!.uid).get().addOnSuccessListener { document ->

                                            if (document != null) {

                                                val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
                                                val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
                                                val acceptDate = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.time)

                                                val eFullName = document.get("ename").toString() + " " + document.get("esurname").toString()
                                                val eCompany = document.get("ecompany").toString()

                                                database.collection("users").document(uID).get().addOnSuccessListener { document ->


                                                    val uName = document.get("name").toString()
                                                    val uPhonenumber = document.get("phonenumber").toString()
                                                    val serviceAccept = EmployeeServiceAccept(acceptDate, serviceID, Location, serviceType, uComment, uName, uPhonenumber, false)

                                                    database.collection("employees").document(mAuth.currentUser!!.uid).collection("acceptedservices").document(serviceID).set(serviceAccept)
                                                    database.collection("services").document(serviceID).update("acceptedby", eFullName + ", " + eCompany)
                                                    database.collection("users").document(uID).collection("services").document(serviceID).update("acceptedby", eFullName + ", " + eCompany)
                                                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Service Accepted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()



                                                }


                                            }


                                        }


                                    }


                                }

                            } else {

                                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Failed to accept service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                            }
```

Comment: *but in my DB there is no collection "services" under employees* but it exists as a top-level collection, right? What's wrong with that?

Comment: @AlexMamo nothing wrong with that. That collection is there to store all the services data (serviceID, serviceCat etc...) but in the collection "employees" there is no collection "services" but when I query the documents underneath that Collection it returns the document as not null (meaning it exists). Later on there will be data underneath the collection "employee",sub collection "services" but as of now there is no data there and my query still return the documents as non null

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot see any subcollections under "fo3 ... Qm2" document. Can you please show it to us?

Comment: @AlexMamo Thats the problem... There is no collection but my query returns that there is one. The code I pasted in the post checks if there is anything under that collection where "serviceAccepted" = false ("which currently does not exist") if not the employee can accept the service.

Comment: So you say that `Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"You already have a service active!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()` is showed, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo, Yes everytime no matter what i do

Comment: Ok, I'll write you an answer right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using the [Task.addOnSuccessListener(OnSuccessListener)](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/tasks/Task.html#addOnSuccessListener(com.google.android.play.core.tasks.OnSuccessListener%3C?%20super%20ResultT%3E)) method on a [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query) object, the result that you get can be a success or a failure, **never** both and **never** null. It will always be one, or the other.

That being said, you should never check the `documents` object against nullity because it can **never** be null. What you should do instead, is to check the "documents" object, which is of type [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QuerySnapshot) to see if [isEmpty()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QuerySnapshot#isEmpty()) or not:

```
if (!documents.isEmpty){
    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"You already have a service active!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
} else {
    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"You don't have a service active!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Where indeed the Toast message from the "else" part of the statement will be displayed, as there are no documents present in the QuerySnapshot object:

```
"You don't have a service active!"
```

Comment: Fixed my problem! Working wonderfully thank you Alex.